# SSIS convert datetime string to date yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: string, datetime, ssis, derived-column

I have a SSIS package that reads a csv file, one of the columns contains a date-time string such:

```
DatePaid
2020-12-03 15:22:45
```

I am using the derived columns transformation editor, and would like to find out how can the date-time string can be converted to only date.

Will it be like this:

```
(DT_DBDATE)[DatePaid]
```

Is it possible to get some help with an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract just the date from a SQL datetime value in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924717/how-do-i-extract-just-the-date-from-a-sql-datetime-value-in-ssis)

Comment: Can it be done in the derived column editor?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a new column `DatePaidConverted` and add `(DT_DBDATE)[DatePaid]` in the `Expression`. In your destination, map `DatePaidConverted` to `[DatePaid]`